# Prove that a set characterized by the jump of a function has a finite number of elements

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In order to build the proof of theorem 3 of page 82 of  the second edition of G de Barra's "Measure Theory and Integration", I'm supposed to prove the following:

> Let $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb{R} $ be a finite-valued, non-decreasing  function and suppose $f$ is constant in $[a-1, a]$ and in $[b, b+1]$. Define the $\textbf{jump}$ of a function at $x$, $\delta f(x)$ as:
> $$\delta f(x)= \inf_{h>0}{f(x+h)} - \sup_{h>0}{f(x-h)} \quad \forall x \in [a,b]$$
> Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, show that the set
> $$E_n= \left\{x \in [a,b] : \delta f(x)>\frac1n \right\}$$
> has at most $n (f(b) -f(a))$ elements.

The textbook mentions and I have proved that;

> - $f$ is continous at $x$ if and only if said **jump** is zero.
> - The set of discontinuities of $f$ is the union of $E_n$ which is at most countable.

Though I feel I should use some arguments I used while proving these last points, I fail to see how to build an initial argument for this problem nor a complete strategy so I figured someone could guide me in the right direction here.

Comment: Please use a more discriptive title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sketched a proof below, explaining my thought process. I'll leave it to you to fill in the details.

$f$ is non-decreasing, so left and right limits necessarily exist everywhere, but may fail to match each other at at most a countable number of points. The function *jumps* at such a point, and $\delta f(x)$ records the size of this jump.

Convince yourself that $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \delta f(x)$ is well defined, and note that it measures the total amount by which $f$ jumps. This can be no bigger than $f(b) - f(a)$.

$E_n$ is the set of points with jumps bigger than $\frac{1}{n}$, and $f$ can only jump by a finite amount overall. This limits the number of such points you can have. Take it home from here.

Comment: It is better not to answer duplicates.